# Log4net not logging on Azure Webapp

Tags: c#, azure, azure-web-app-service, log4net

For a web service, I have log4net configured and working fine locally but not when the webapp is deployed on Azure Webapp. The directory is created but there is nothing logged at the file..

Here is my config:

```
<log4net>
<appender name="RollingFile" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
  <file value="log/sms.log" />
  <appendToFile value="true" />
  <maximumFileSize value="10MB" />
  <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%date %level - %message%newline" />
  </layout>
</appender>
<logger name="TheLogger">
  <appender-ref ref="RollingFile" />
</logger>
```

Within my AssemblyInfo.cs I have:

```
[assembly: XmlConfigurator(Watch = true)]
```

At the Startup class i have :

```
public static ILog Logger { get; private set; }

    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder appBuilder)
    {
        Logger = LogManager.GetLogger("TheLogger");
        Logger.Info("Application start...");
    }
```

Clearly my configuration is being picked up because in my log file is written the hour/date format and also Application start... but not the logging information.
What am i missing?

Comment: Same problem here, empty log files. Normally the logger should log in all cases. It works on my machine...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you don't forget to add the `root` configuration.
Are compiling for Debug and deploying in Azure in Release mode?

```
<log4net>
  <root>
    <level value="INFO" />
    <appender-ref ref="RollingFile" />
  </root>
  <appender name="RollingFile" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
   <!-- ... -->
  </appender>
</log4net>
```

Comment: Yes in release mode, tried adding the `root` configuration and still not working

Comment: @E.Hysenaj Is it at least creating the "log" folder? Have you tried to specify a file name without a folder? It seems you have created everything needed.

Comment: it is creating the "log" folder and it also has the log file as a specified..no i haven't

Comment: Oh okay! Is it not just the buffer? Log4Net usually buffers some amount of data before committing it to a file. Try to write more things on the log. Take a look at the `losy` property: https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/config-examples.html

Comment: Now, with the same configurations as i had, it's not appending anything anymore, not even the `Application Start`...it's driving me crazy

Comment: Make sure that log4net.config file is copied to the bin\folder when building (set to 'Copy if newer' in compiler)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and found a solution. I had to replace these 2 lines of code in the Program class of the .Net Core API:

```
XmlDocument log4netConfig = new XmlDocument();
log4netConfig.Load(File.OpenRead("log4net.config"));
```

With this:

```
var logRepository = LogManager.GetRepository(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly());
XmlConfigurator.Configure(logRepository, new FileInfo("log4net.config"));
```

The reason is because in .Net Framework API's I used the assembly attribute to set this, now I need to do it like this.